# Why not use exact probability in 0.632 or 0.632+ method with small sample size?

Tags: bootstrap, error, estimators, in-sample

The .632 estimator (and extensions like .632+) developed by Bradley Efron are founded on the following premise. Suppose we have a data set with $n$ observations, and we draw $B$ nonparametric bootstrap samples (that is, each bootstrap sample consists of $n$ observations sampled with replacement with equal probabilities from the original sample).

The probability that the $i$th observation appears at least once in the $b$th bootstrap sample, for any $i\in\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$ and $b\in\left\{1,2,\ldots,B\right\}$, is $1-\left(1-1/n\right)^n$, as is easily shown from the binomial distribution with $p=1/n$. And $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}1-\left(1-1/n\right)^n=1-e^{-1}\approx 0.632$. This leads to an argument for using weights of $1-0.632$ and $0.632$ in a weighted average of the training error and the out-of-bootstrap error respectively to obtain an estimate of in-sample prediction error.

This is fine and good for large $n$. However, for small $n$, the probability can be quite far from $0.632$; for instance, for $n=10$, $1-\left(1-1/n\right)^n\approx 0.651$. Yet checking the source code for R functions implementing .632 or .632+ estimators (e.g., [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/sortinghat/src/R/errorest-632plus.r)), they just use the weight $0.632$ in the estimator regardless of sample size. Would this not be a non-trivial source of bias for small sample sizes, and would it not therefore be better to always use a weight of $1-\left(1-1/n\right)^n$ rather than $0.632$?

Comment: I have never seen someone suggesting to use weights as you propose. Do you have any references for that?

Comment: No; I've never seen it done either and that's why I asked. Maybe such small datasets as $n=10$ are so seldom used nowadays that the issue seldom comes up? It occurred to me that maybe the probabilistic argument for the 0.632 rule depends on the limiting probability regardless of the $n$ used in a particular scenario. But when I went back to Efron's 1983 JASA paper, it seems that the only rationale for $0.632$ that he gives is as an approximation to $1-(1-1/n)^n$.

Comment: The in-sample error is the error on the training data, which you presumably have access to. Why do you need to estimate it?

Comment: As used here, following the language used in Elements of Statistical Learning, in-sample error refers to the error on new responses at the original design points. The in-sample error is thus not known, and the training error (which is known) is an overly optimistic estimate of it.

Comment: Is the 0.02 probability difference really that big? At such small sample sizes, it might as well be noise.